# iPod Touch running really slow

Tags: ipod-touch

My iPod has been running really slow and the battery has been draining much faster than normal. The battery has a full charge in the morning, by my lunch hour (4 hours later) playing just audio, the battery is down to 50%. Normally, as of a couple weeks ago, the battery is around 90% at lunch time.

Would a "format" and "reinstall" fix that?

Clarifications: I have "rebooted" a few times and it is not jailbroken.

Comment: Note to flaggers: iPhones and other "smart" mobile devices are generally acceptable on SuperUser. Since the iPod Touch is nearly identical to the iPhone, it stands to reason that it also falls under the banner of acceptable material.

Comment: The PSP can function perfectly well as a pure media device, and the iphone can function pefectly well as  a pure gaming device. Is it purely marketing as to whether it's allowed?

Comment: Do you have Bluetooth disabled, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update to my problem, I had to do a restore then basically reset everything from scratch. Restoring the backup only brought back the problem.

Comment: When you went to post this, an alert box popped up saying "If you're responding to answers left on your question, use the comments link under each answer."

Can you please refrain from posting answers that aren't answers? This post would be better suited as a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: This IS the answer. This is what I did to resolve my issue. No one else answered my question, so I had to answer it myself to close the loop. Is that wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a "restore". :)

Anyway, before you do a restore, trying doing a "reset" first. If not, do a "restore" and there is a **very high chance** that the problem will go away.

Comment: I'll do that first then. I wish it didn't take so long to do.

Comment: A reset is pretty fast. A restore is long... but hey, you could always surf App Store while doing it. ;)

Comment: This is what I recommend also. It is nice to just start fresh.

Comment: This did not work for me. The problems came back.

Answer (score 0):

Is it jailbroken? Have you installed any background app if so? Backgrounder and Intelliscreen are two major culprits.

Otherwise, do you have push set to some frequent amount of time?

Comment: I have WiFi disabled while at work (no wifi anyway) and added clarification that it is not jailbroken.